# Link preview not shown on any soacial media

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, yoast

I was testing to see how my links appear when it's shared on whatsapp or other social media, I found that it only shows the link, but not the meta description and page/post image etc.

I use the latest wordpress version btw and Yoast SEO plugin.

How to fix it?

Comment: You should either share code, or if you want support for software and plugins you are using, find a better place to ask this question.

Comment: I don't have code. I am using a ready theme.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about SEO/webmastering and is better suited to the Webmasters stack. However, without any code it's going to be impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Social media takes time to get your updated description and post images and other details that does not effect at a time and yes you can use the Sharing Debugger to see the information that is used when your website content is shared on Facebook, Messenger and other places via this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/